# Instrumental Variable with Conditional Randomization?

Tags: regression, interaction, econometrics, causality, instrumental-variables

I am doing a study with an IV design. In my setting, the IV is only conditionally random within a year and within a cohort. In this case, do I simply include year and cohort as controls in the IV regression? To be clear, the following is the regression I am currently running:

```r
iv_model <- ivreg(y ~ D + factor(year) + factor(cohort) | Z + 
                      factor(year) + factor(cohort) , data=data)
```

Do I need to include any interaction terms?

Comment: Have you tried factor(year):factor(cohort)? If you know that Z is only random within a year AND cohort I guess this would be the correct specification. However, you would presumably be discarding a lot of (potentially also random) variation in Z...